# Chromedriver 2.36 with chrome v65 giving exception

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have recently updated ChromeDriver to 2.36 after chrome was auto updated to v65.

But on running test now i am getting below exceptions

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 10482
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to write automation extension zip
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 218 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: '172.16.27.222', ip: '172.16.123.114', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Have tried both chromeOptions & DesiredCapabilties

```
ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();
o.addArguments("disable-extensions");
o.addArguments("--start-maximized");
ChromeDriver chromeDriver  = new ChromeDriver(o);
return chromeDriver;
```

Also tried below method :

```
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Update your `java` version and see if it changes anything!

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to write automation extension zip
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 218 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: '172.16.27.222', ip: '172.16.123.114', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

It is clear from your error stack trace that the **driver.version** is not getting recognized.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- You are using *chrome=65.0* (as per your question)
- You are using *Selenium Client v3.11.0*
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_77** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u77* , *Selenium Client v3.11.0* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.36*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `@Test`.

### Additional Considerations

- If you intend to use *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser*, while initializing the *WebDriver* instance instead of using the *ChromeDriver* implementation use the *WebDriver* interface as follows :

  ```
  WebDriver chromeDriver =  new ChromeDriver(o);
  ```
- If you intend to maximize the browser window, instead of using `chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();` use the `ChromeOptions` instance as follows :

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the arguments I use:

```
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("enable-automation");
args.add("test-type=browser");
args.add("disable-plugins");
args.add("disable-infobars");
args.add("disable-extensions");
options.put("args", args);
```

I think you need to at least add the "enable-automation" argument.